# ClojureScript clojure.set?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

How can I use clojure.set in ClojureScript?

I always get a error.

```
(def middle-land (set (for [x water-hor
                            y (vec (clojure.set/difference (set (range 0 board-side))
                                                           (set water-ver)))]
                    [x y])))

ReferenceError: clojure is not defined
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Seems you need to explicitly require the namespace to be able to use it:

```
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (ns core (:require clojure.set))
ClojureScript:core> (clojure.set/difference #{1 2} #{1 4}) ;=> #{2}
```

Comment: You need to explicitly include `clojure.set` in Clojure as well.

Comment: @dnolen, is it some Leiningen "magic" that enables me to do this with plain Clojure then?

Comment: @dnolen Why does this clojure.set/difference work in clojure and not in clojurescript? I just copied the code over.

Comment: @ponzao yes Leiningen adds some namespaces to their REPL for convenience.

Comment: @dnolen, thanks for the clarification. Based on a quick experiment Leiningen seems to do this for other "goals" as well (`lein midje` worked without an explicit `require` also`).