# Clojurescript clojure.set not working

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I've referenced [ClojureScript clojure.set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367433/clojurescript-clojure-set) and can only get the docstring to come up, but actually running any of the `clojure.set` function doesn't work.  Using ClojureScript 0.0-3126 on Opera 28.0 and/or Chrome 41.0.2272.101 m on Windows 7 x64.

Any ideas on how to correct this?
thanks

```
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (require '[clojure.set])
nil
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (doc clojure.set/union)
-------------------------
clojure.set/union
([] [s1] [s1 s2] [s1 s2 & sets])
  Return a set that is the union of the input sets
nil
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (clojure.set/union #{:a} #{:b})
TypeError: Cannot read property 'union' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'union' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8888/js/coreweb.js:45250:260), <anonymous>:1:100)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8888/js/coreweb.js:45250:260), <anonymous>:9:3)
    at eval (ev al at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8888/js/coreweb.js:45250:260), <anonymous>:14:4)
    at http://localhost:8888/js/coreweb.js:45250:255
    at clojure$browser$repl$evaluate_javascript (http://localhost:8888/js/coreweb.js:45256:4)
    at Object.callback (http://localhost:8888/js/coreweb.js:45421:181)
    at goog.messaging.AbstractChannel.deliver (http://localhost:8888/js/coreweb.js:42499:13)
    at goog.net.xpc.CrossPageChannel.xpcDeliver (http://localhost:8888/js/coreweb.js:43463:14)
    at Function.goog.net.xpc.NativeMessagingTransport.messageReceived_ (http://localhost:8888/js/coreweb.js:42859:13)
    at Object.goog.events.fireListener (http://localhost:8888/js/coreweb.js:39835:21)
```

Comment: This is a weird error you are getting. After following the instructions [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start) for getting a working REPL I get no errors when evaluating the code you posted. Granted I didn't try the specific ClojureScript version you mentioned, I just downloaded the jar linked in that guide, so it might be an bug in the `0.0-3126` version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's more personal research than an answer. Still, I did reproduce your problem in Chrome (on MAC) taking the ClojureScript [Quick Start](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start).

If the cljs server repl file is as follow (i.e. there is no `require` on `clojure.set`):

```
(ns hello-world.core
  (:require [clojure.browser.repl :as repl]))

(defonce conn
   (repl/connect "http://localhost:9000/repl"))

(enable-console-print!)
(println "Hello world!")
```

and the `repl.clj` is:

```
(require 'cljs.repl)
(require 'cljs.closure)
(require 'cljs.repl.browser)

(cljs.closure/build "src"
                    {:main 'hello-world.core
                     :output-to "out/main.js"
                     :verbose true})

(cljs.repl/repl (cljs.repl.browser/repl-env)
                :watch "src"
                :output-dir "out")
```

Then starting the repl in a terminal with:

```
rlwrap java -cp cljs.jar:src clojure.main repl.clj
```

And connecting the browser on `http://localhost:9000`, then this works:

```
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (require '[clojure.set])
nil
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (clojure.set/union #{6} #{9} #{7})
#{7 6 9}
```

Now, if you *reload* the server page `http://localhost:9000`, and try again, I had the problem (doc is available on the *symbol*, but the *var* is not there anymore):

```
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (doc clojure.set/union)
-------------------------
clojure.set/union
([] [s1] [s1 s2] [s1 s2 & sets])
  Return a set that is the union of the input sets
nil
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (clojure.set/union #{6} #{9} #{7})
TypeError: Cannot read property 'union' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'union' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/out/clojure/browser/repl.js:42:272), <anonymous>:1:100)
```

If you modify the cljs server file to `require` `clojure.set`, i.e

```
(ns hello-world.core
      (:require [clojure.browser.repl :as repl]
                [clojure.set]))
```

Then, it looks like you still need to require clojure.set from the repl in order to use its functions, but then, you can reload the server page and it still works in the repl.